# Regarding saving text file in c programming

Tags: c

I try to get an idea how to save a text file while i keep the user write the name of this text file.

```
char filename[20];
gets(filename);
fp = fopen ( filename, "wb+");
```

When I save it, it will not be a text file.

I can do it by `f=fopen("file.txt", "r")` but I want the name is chosen by the user.

Comment: What does "it will not be a text file" mean? Did you maybe expect the *extension* `.txt` automagically gets added?

Comment: yes, i can do it by f=fopen("file.txt",  "r"); but i want the name is chosen by the user.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

First get file name:

```
char name[100] = {0};
fgets (name, 100, stdin);
```

Then create text file:

```
// Open as text file
FILE *f = fopen(name, "w");
if (f == NULL)
{
    printf("Error opening file!\n");
    exit(1);
}

// write some text 
const char *text = "Write this to the file";
fprintf(f, "Some text: %s\n", text);

fclose(f);
```

Comment: @Abdullah Mohammed: what do you mean its not saved as txt? Enter name test.txt